# Add information to knowledge panel

Tags: google-knowledge-graph

My friend had knowledge panel but with wrong main photo , we are complain so many times to wrong photo and google just deleted all info unless info from Wikipedia. How to add information to knowledge panel ?not like business causevia that way need to share real address.

Comment: Can’t post screenshot cause rank too low.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend completing a Google My Business profile, it's free. https://www.google.com/business/

Secondly, add structured data schema markup to your website with the information you'd like to appear in the KP.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know of associating the right picture with a person is to use that picture consistently.

Use the picture on all websites you can change the picture and that has a page related to the person. For example, Twitter profile, Facebook profile, Wordpress Blog profile, Gravatar, ... .

The second best is to have a home page for that person, that you technically control and add schema markup to the page as a ProfilePage, or AboutPage, including the "about" clause, describing a record of type  "Person". In that record, you add an image (the same as used above AND shown on the HTML of the page). - This method is actually the best, but it is so technical, that not many people can execute it.

- https://schema.org/AboutPage
- https://schema.org/Person